# add a class to the input element of ngTagsInput

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

So I am using the [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) library, and I am trying to get it to style like the rest of my website.

In order for that to work, I need to add a class to the input element that is built by the tags-input directive.

The problem is that if I add a class to the tag, it styles the container div, and that is not what I am looking for, just to add a style to the input element.

Comment: I guess this works. Any better ideas?

`$(".tags .input").addClass('form-control')`

Comment: you cannot. You have two solution: 1) modify the ngTagsInput directive when put the `<li>` and you can add the class or 2) replace the class of the tag `tag-item` in your css (i did the same).

Comment: look at this example: http://embed.plnkr.co/0ukNPz/preview
you can modify the input style by changing `.bootstrap .tags` class